# Redash google login

Tags: oauth, google-signin, redash

I am using redash/redash:10.1.0.b50633 version. I want co-workers to log in my redash server with company's domain.

I tried the docs below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DgBG.png)
but when I try to do NO.5, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyEu4.png)
I can't find the box **Allowed Google Apps Domains**